# Processing JSON or XML in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, json

I am uploading JSON data to a rails app through an HTTP Post.I am a rails newbie and I do not understand how to process json or xml in the controller of my rails app. I can find info for processing form data, but not posted json or xml. please direct me to a book, tutorial, guide or code that tackels this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Rails is very good about being magical with this sort of thing...you might first go look at the server output for the post and see what is in the parameters.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you are correctly setting the content type header in the HTTP Post, any XML or JSON **should** be parsed automatically and placed in the `params` hash which is then available in the action (in the controller).

For example, if you put this in the content body:

```
{
  'name': 'John',
  'occupation': 'foe'
}
```

... and set the content type header to `application/json` when making the HTTP Post, then you can do something like this in your controller:

```
def process
  @person = Person.new
  @person.first_name = params['name']
  @person.occupation = params['occupation']
end
```

Comment: Pleasure @BigEd. If the answer works out for you then please do upvote it and mark it as the correct answer. Thanks :)